# Reordering array using .sort with parameters

Tags: javascript

I have a function to reorder an array with objects inside and I call that function with the object property I want to sort, but I don't know how to set the callback function to use the parameter. I tried use eval() but with no success. It's not working correctly.

```
function order(param){
  const newOrder = arrayContent.sort((first,second) => (`${first}.${param}` > `${second}.${param}`) ? 1 : -1);
};
order('name')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy to implement.
You can refer to object either with 'dot notation' e.g. `object.name` or with help of square brackets e.g. `object['name']` where you could put any string inside brackets to refer to certain 'inner field'

```js
let arrayContent = [{number:3,name:'Alice'},{number:2, name:'Maxim'}]; //your array
    let order = param => arrayContent.sort((first,second) => first[param] < second[param]?1:-1);
    
    order('name');
    console.log(arrayContent);
    order('number');
    console.log(arrayContent);
```

Comment: Oh... thanks... using the '[ ]' instead '${ }'... I don't understand why, but for now it's ok. Thanks again

Comment: @asaks-, the back-tick with ${} is for string interpolation, so your attempt was *appending* the object prop name, not accessing the prop.  Square braces say, "lookup the prop whose name is the result of the expression inside the brackets"... i.e. `first[param]` when param is `'name'` says get me the name prop from the first object.